# Sitecore Japanese content showing question mark

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

I am using Sitecore 8.2. The content appears fine for all the languages except for language like Japanese.

Some of the characters are displayed as diamond question mark. We are using utf-8 encoding in meta tag.

Comment: what 's your site's font ?

Comment: The problem seems coming from 2 things: either wrong character encoding usage or font setting used to display Japanese characters.

Comment: We are using utf-8 encoding

Comment: I assume you mean that it works well in the Sitecore content editor, but in the page editor or CD not, looks like you use a font that misses some of the Japanese characters, try another font.

Comment: In the sitecore content editor->in the rich text editor it is displaying proeperly but when we publish and view the page some of the characters are showing question mark.

Comment: And which font file do you use?

Comment: we are using brandon font taken from adobe typekit